# Topology query in geosparql

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege, geosparql

I have inspired [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.371.1518&rep=rep1&type=pdf) articles and created an ontology with using geosparql ontology. Two classes named Area and Park were created as subclasses of the Feature class of geosparql. 3 Area instances and 1 Park instance were added to the ontology. Then, geometry instances were created (asWKT) as a subclass of Polygon class of geosparql. And the geometry instances were related with the Park and Area instances via hasGeometry object property ([The created ontology and instances](https://files.fm/u/neyqwa95#_)).

I have tried to make a topology query to find out which Area instances are within the Park instance. So, I have run the below query with using the sparql query plugin of Protégé 4.3.

PREFIX geosparql: http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#
PREFIX su: http://www.example.org/su#

SELECT ?x ?y
WHERE {
?x a su:Area ;
geosparql:hasGeometry ?xgeo .
?y a su:Park ;
geosparql:hasGeometry ?ygeo .
?xgeo geosparql:sfWithin ?ygeo .
}

No results return but I know that there are two Area instances within the Park instance. I did not find out the problem. Do not I query topological relations with using geosparql and protégé?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't import the "good" use of `sfWithin` entity.

There is a difference between 
`http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#sfWithin` and `http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/sfWithin`.

Actually, I don't understand yet how to proceed in Protégé with this statement, I'm sorry about that.

If you really need to use such a topology query, you can use [GraphDB](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/) instead, which implements a good working plugin for GeoSPARQL.

Comment: Actually, used in a SPARQL FILTER, this statement call an external Java function that implements the RCC8, 9DE-IM, ... As I said, GraphDB implements such functions.